# Checking if a vector space has a basis consisting of eigenvectors of an operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(\text{Mat}(2,2,\mathbb{C}))$ be defined as $T \left(\begin{array} \\
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array} \\
2a-ib & ia+3c \\
3b-2c & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
$

**Question:** Does $\text{Mat}(2,2,\mathbb{C})$ have a basis consisting of eigenvectors of $T$?

**Attempt:** I am not even sure if this is true or not.

Note that the above statement is equivalent to showing either of the following:-

$(1)$ $T$ is diagonalizable.

$(2)$ There exist $1$-dimensional subspaces $U_1, \ldots, U_n$ of $V$ each invariant under $T$ such that $V=U_1 \bigoplus \ldots \bigoplus U_n$.

$(3)$ $\text{dim} V= \text{dim} E(\lambda_1,T)+ \ldots +\text{dim} E(\lambda_m,T)$.

It clear that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. But, finding other eigenvalues is not possible by hand. I have this feeling that we the only way to do this is use $(2)$ somehow.

Any hint in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Use the basis of $4$ elementary $2\times 2$ matrices to represent $T$  as a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Comment: How does that help? It is not upper triangular with respect to the standard basis. And, as said in the question, I can't calculate the eigenvalues with hand.

Comment: Yes, I know using determinants, but that is not allowed. The characteristic polynomial which we get in that scenario is $\lambda^2(\lambda-2)(\lambda+2)=0$ since the last column contains $0$ for the first three entries. But, now my problem is that $2$ and $-2$ are not eigenvalues of $T$. Am I doing a calculation mistake?

Comment: The matrix for $T$ is $\left( \begin{array}\\ 2 & -i & 0 & 0 \\
i & 0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & -2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{array} \right)$

Comment: You need to determine whether that 4-by-4 matrix is diagonalisable. Now, real symmetric matrices are always diagonalisable, but that's not real, and not symmetric....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown First, see my second comment to this post. Next, what should I do? I told you it is very difficult to calculate eigenvalues by hand.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Is your hint even in the right direction? Don't just shoot in the dark. It unnecessarily makes things difficult for the question asker and the commenter doesn't gain anything out of it.

Comment: @user330477 You most certainly can use Lord Shark's hint because your matrix is Hermitian. And, he is not in the habit of shooting in the dark. Some other users are, but... there are answerers who know what they are talking about. I guess his main point was not to try and calculate the eigenvalues but to apply a suitable general theorem.